# Overlay divs in css

Tags: html, css, angular

I'd like to implement a process spinner for my application durting a rest call process. My problem now is that I'd like to overlay a div with another one which contains the spinner but I just don't know how. I tried it with z-index, but it is not working. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Here a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6qtbp-qgvkx1

Comment: what do you mean inherits the spinner

Comment: are you using angular?

Comment: You should add "position" to your css. Z-index alone wont do anything. position:absolute; is positioned according to the first parent having a position itself. position:fixed; is positioned according to the window of your browser.

Read more about it here:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: But if I'm adding position absolute, with (top, right, bottom, left) i won't we responsive anymore because the overlay div should always be as big as the the div below.

Comment: @NewUser Yes I'm using angular

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code **in the question itself**, not just on a third-party site. There is a help center article on how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

z-index is just about stacking over (where div appears on top or below, et al). to overlay divs, you should definitely use positioning properties (position, top, left, right, et al). from the URL provided, I can't really figure out the divs you want to overlay.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean full page loader like this

```
 <div class="loader">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
```

`

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.spinner {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: 10px solid teal;
  position: fixed;
  left: calc( 50% - 30px);
  top: calc( 50% - 30px);
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```